# Layout adapting depending on Screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a problem with Android Studio when I have to adapt my application to different screen sizes. I tried creating diferent layouts depending on the screen size (small, normal, large, xlarge), but it doesn't work and I don't know why. No matter what the screen size of the mobile is, it uses the normal screen size layout. Here I leave you 2 screenshots: The first one is the res folder in the explorer, and the second one the folders in android studio.

[Res folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXxco.jpg)

[Android Studio folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuSbr.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
//create a folder structure like this

/layout
/layout-sw300dp
/layout-sw400dp
/layout-sw600dp
/layout-sw800dp
```

Now you can place the respective layout files in the corresponding folders!

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: 1.- I do have to keep also a default layout folder right?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely keep the default folder